# Datetime Equivalent of Date(Now()) for Insert

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to insert NOW() in a datetime format - "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" in a column of the type "text".

Currently I am using:

```
INSERT INTO table (mycol) VALUES (DATE(NOW()))
```

But this inserts the date in the format "YYYY-MM-DD".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **[DATE_FORMAT()](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)**

Something like this,

```
INSERT INTO tablename (sample) VALUES (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S'))
```

or simple

```
insert into tablename values(now());
```

## [*SQLFIDDLE Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10b03/1)

Answer (score 2):

Just `NOW()` will give you that result, since you're then not casting to `DATE` first.

Comment: `DATETIME(NOW())` results in a syntax error. `NOW()` works though.

Comment: @ColorWP.com - oops, sorry. I saw the cast to `DATE` earlier and assumed similar would work for `DATETIME`. I've fixed the answer to reflect it - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [DATE_FORMAT(date,format)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p')
```

Comment: Why is that required? `NOW()` is already in the format you specified.