# select data on specific date

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to retrieve records from db according to date format YYYY,MM,dd given by me but the column type is YYYY,MM,dd hh:mm:ss.

tried to use Date format function

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tabl.error_logs 
 where created_at = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d'- INTERVAL 3 DAY);
```

I expect the created date will be 2019-06-08, but the result is empty

Comment: That looks pretty strange - what should that `INTERVAL 3 DAY` part in between do?

Comment: @NicoHaase this returns the date before 3 days from now

Comment: its helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264417/datetime-equivalent-of-datenow-for-insert?rq=1 @user3210456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the actual datatype of `created_at` column?

This answer is going to ignore that funkiness with the format with commas, and assume that it's not character type data, and that it's `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.

Normative pattern for predicates on `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` columns is a range comparison.

For example, to get all datetimecol values on June 10th, then something like this:

```
 WHERE t.datetimecol >= '2019-06-10 00:00:00'
   AND t.datetimecol  < '2019-06-11 00:00:00'
```

Typically, I would just pass that one date value, and let MySQL figure out the next day. If we omit the time portion, MySQL will assume `00:00:00`

```
 WHERE t.datetimecol >= '2019-06-10' + INTERVAL 0 DAY
   AND t.datetimecol  < '2019-06-10' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

---

For performance, to allow MySQL to make effective use of a range scan operation on a suitable index, we want to *avoid* wrapping the column reference in a function. That is, specifying  `DATE(t.datetimecol)` in a condition in the WHERE clause is going to force MySQL to evaluate the `DATE()` function on every row in the table.

With references to the bare column, that allows MySQL to make use of an index, if a suitable index is available.

---

e.g.

```
SELECT e.* 
  FROM tabl.error_logs e
 WHERE e.created_at  >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -3 DAY 
   AND e.created_at  <  DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -2 DAY
```

note that we can easily test those expressions in the WHERE clause, to verify they are returning what we want, and tweak as necessary:

```
 SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -3 DAY
      , DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -2 DAY
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your query [sargable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable), you need ...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tabl.error_logs 
 WHERE created_at >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
  AND created_at <  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

This selects all values of `created_at` on or after midnight three days ago, up to but not including `<` midnight two days ago. It uses a range scan on an index on `created_at` if one is available.

Comment: +10 inequality comparisons on *bare* columns (not wrapped in a function) will allow MySQL to use an index range scan operation if a suitable index is available. +10

Answer (score 0):

You coudl use date_sub()

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabl.error_logs 
where date(created_at) = DATE_SUB(date(now()), INTERVAL 3 DAY);
```

if the column created_at is a date then you could avoid the date() function and let the index (if present) work for this column

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabl.error_logs 
where created_at = DATE_SUB(date(now()), INTERVAL 3 DAY);
```

Comment: Note that this solution cannot use an index

Comment: obviously  .. there are functions in where clause

Comment: Specifically, a function on a column

Comment: exactly but is not clear the format for the column .. if is already a date  or if is a datetime ..